# bubble sorting of Array in c

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, codeblocks

I Made a selection and  bubble sort for the array , the selection sort is ok ,but the bubble sort start sorting from the element no  (5) of the array and from {0 to 4} no sorting

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

////  Makeing a swaping Function/////
void swap(int* x,int* y)
{
    int temp= *y;
    *y= *x;
    *x= temp;
}

////  Makeing a sorting  Function  selection_ sort/////
void selection_sort_elements(int array[],int len)
{
    int i,j;
    int flag =1;
 for (i=0;i<len;i++)
 {
     printf("Number of Iteration: %d \n",i);
     for(j=i+1;j<len;j++)
     {

         if(array[i]>array[j])
         {
             swap(&array[i],&array[j]);
         }
     }
 }

}
////  Makeing a sorting  Function  Bubble sort/////
void bubble_sort_elements(int array[],int len)
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    //int flag =1;
 for (i = 0; i < len ;i++)
 {
     printf("Number of Iteration: %d \n",i);

     //if(flag == 0){
         //   return;
         //}
         //flag=0;
     for(j = i+1 ; j < len ;j++)
     {
         if(array[j] < array[j-1])
         {
            // flag=1;
             swap(&array[j],&array[j-1]);
         }
     }
 }

}

int main()
{
    int arr[10];
    int i=0;
    printf("Please Enter A Five Element Of The Array\n");
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        }

    printf(" You Entered The Array:");
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
        printf(" %d ", arr[i]);
        }

    bubble_sort_elements(arr,sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));      // Calling Sorting Function

    printf("\n Now We Sorted Your Array :");
    for (i=0;i<sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);i++)
        {
        printf(" %d ", arr[i]);
        }

    //Getting The max Number in the array and its position
    printf("\n The MAX Number In The Array IS %d And it location is %d ", arr[(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))-1], sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])-1);
    //Getting The Min Number in the array and its position
    printf("\n The Min Number In The Array IS %d And it location is %d ", arr[0], sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])-sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));

    return 0;
}
```

I  Made a selection and  bubble sort for the array , the selection sort is ok ,but the bubble sort start sorting from the element no  (5) of the array and from {0 to 4} no sorting
I uploaded image for the response

[image]

Comment: Compile your code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`, improve your code to get no warnings (see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)...) then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand what is going wrong in your program. If allowed, take inspiration from existing open source programs (like [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or many others on https://github.com/ ...). Read also wikipedia on [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) and the documentation of your  C compiler

Answer (score 2):

Your bubble-sort algorithm is wrong. You either need an ascending sweep with a continuously reduced ceiling, or a descending sweep with a continuously advanced floor. You have an ascending sweep with a continuously advancing floor. Your inner loop should be `for (j = 1; j<(len-i); ++j)` if you want to keep the ascending sweep, but fix the algorithm to use a continuously reduced ceiling.

```
void bubble_sort_elements(int array[], size_t len)
{
    size_t i = 0, j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("Number of Iteration: %zu \n", i);

        for (j = 1; j<(len-i); ++j)
        {
            if (array[j] < array[j - 1])
            {
                // flag=1;
                swap(&array[j], &array[j - 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can forego the `i` and just continuously reduce `len` on the outer loop:

```
void bubble_sort_elements(int array[], size_t len)
{
    while (len-- > 0)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j<len; ++j)
        {
            if (array[j+1] < array[j])
                swap(array+j, array+j+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, if you want swap detection to short-circuit an already-sorted sequence once it falls into place, the latter algorithm is immediately adaptable to that:

```
void bubble_sort_elements(int array[], size_t len)
{
    int swapped = 1;
    while (len-- > 0 && swapped)
    {
        swapped = 0;
        for (size_t j = 0; j<len; ++j)
        {
            if (array[j+1] < array[j])
            {
                swap(array+j, array+j+1);
                swapped = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```